# Mysql remote connect over ssh to a kubernetes pod

Tags: docker, kubernetes, digital-ocean, navicat, sequelpro

Many devops use mysql connect over ssh to access to production database for various reasons and queries

after successfull deploy mysql container to a digital ocean kubernetes cluster
im able to ssh into the pod via :

```
kubectl --kubeconfig="kubeconfig.yaml" exec -it vega-mysql-5df9b745f9-c6859 -c vega-mysql -- /bin/bash
```

my question is how can i remote connect applications like : navicat - sequel pro or mysql workbench to this pod ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nitpick: Even though you can use it to start an interactive shell, `kubectl exec` is not the same as SSH. For that reason, regular MySQL clients that support SSH-tunneled connections, don't (and probably never will) support connecting to a MySQL server tunneled through `kubectl exec`.

Alternative solution: Use [`kubectl port-forward`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/) to forward the Pod's MySQL server port 3306 to your local machine:

```
kubectl port-forward vega-mysql-5df9b745f9-c6859 3306:3306
```

This will instruct kubectl to act as a TCP proxy from a local port on your machine into the Pod. Then, connect to `127.0.0.1:3306` with any MySQL client of your choice:

```
mysql -u youruser -p -h 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: nice , i will post my solution to

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this by expose mysql to a service with random port

```
kubectl --kubeconfig=vega-kubeconfig.yaml expose deployment mysqldeployment --type=NodePort --name=nginx --port=3306 --target-port=3306
```

And connect to it via my client without ssh tunnel.

but @helmbert solution is good also

Comment: While this does work, you should keep in mind that you should do this only when you have SSL set up for your MySQL server (ideally, with `ssl-mode=required`) or your NodePort is reachable only from a network that you trust entirely. Otherwise, you might end up sending your MySQL credentials through the internet in clear text.